# Entity Framework join across two databases

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I have a WebAPI.  I need to return a list of `ActivityRegisters`.  We have a repository that does it like this:

```
public IQueryable<ActivityRegister> GetRegisters(int activityID) 
{
    return ActivityDBContext.ActivityRegisters.Where(x => x.ActivityID == activityID x.IsActive == true).OrderBy(x => x.ActivityRegisterID).AsQueryable();
}
```

However, there is a nullable column on the `ActivityRegister` table called `roomID`.  There is a Rooms table but it is in a different database which we have a `AdminDBContext` for.  I need the API to return the `roomName` in the payload which exists in the Admin DB.  How can I get the above method to return the the `roomName` using the `roomID`?  Thank you, I'm new and learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a join on tables across two different contexts like this:

```
public IQueryable<ActivityRegister> GetRegisters(int activityID) 
{
    var activityRegisters = ActivityDBContext.ActivityRegisters.Where(x => x.ActivityID == activityID x.IsActive == true).OrderBy(x => x.ActivityRegisterID).ToList();
    var roomIdsFromActivityRegisters = activityRegisters.Select(activityRegister => activityRegister.roomID);
    var rooms = AdminDBContext.Rooms.Where(room => roomsIdFromActivityRegisters.Contains(room.Id)).ToList();
    var resultFromJoinAcrossContexts = (from activityRegister in activityRegisters 
                                        join room in rooms on activityRegister.roomID equals room.Id
                                        select new ActivityRegister
                                        {
                                            Room = room,
                                            roomID = room.Id,
                                            Id = activityRegister
                                         });
    return resultFromJoinAcrossContexts.AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: This pulls the whole `Rooms` table into memory! You could at least get the rooms of which the `Id`s occur in `activityRegisters`.

Comment: `Exists`?? I think you mean `Any`. Anyway, you can't use `activityRegisters` in a subsequent EF query just like that.

Comment: And now you've gone full circle back to pulling all rooms from the database again. The point is: create an array of room ids from `activityRegisters` and use that in a `Contains` statement to fetch the relevant rooms only.